# Include Foward Slash in excel formula

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have a set of data that is a # such as "398" I am trying to add a forward slash ( / ) to separate that number with another number. ( 398 / 402 ) output should be something like that. Powershell thinks i am trying to divide by zero.

I have already tried "" / "" , but this did not work.

```
#ADD / Eventually add data

$counter = 2
$endcounter = 11
Write-Host "counter:" $counter

while ($counter -le $endcounter)
{
$countertwo = $counter
$formula = ("=" + "B" + $countertwo + "&" + "" / "")
Write-Host "formula:" $formula
#$counter++
Write-Host "Counter:" $counter
$countertwo = $counter
Write-Host "countertwo:" $countertwo
$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($countertwo,19).Formula = $formula
$counter++
Write-Host "Counter:" $counter
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not escaping your double quotes correctly.  Instead of this:

```
$formula = ("=" + "B" + $countertwo + "&" + "" / "")
```

Try one of these:

```
$formula = ("=" + "B" + $countertwo + "&" + '" / "')
$formula = ("=" + "B" + $countertwo + "&" + """ / """)
$formula = ("=" + "B" + $countertwo + "&" + "`" / `"")
```